# Firebase onchildadded() returns same data 3 times in listview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My problem is the same with title,firebase onchildadded() returns same data 3 times in listview.I tried many things but still couldnt found solution.

My code is there;

```
public void ReceiveMessages(){
     childEventListener = message_dbref.child(user_id).child(user2_id).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);

            message_dbref.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
            user_dbref.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
            messageArrayList.add(message);
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `ReceiveMessages()` method?

Comment: There is an value event listener i call it there

Comment: `childEventListener` is called every time there is change in any child of your parent node, so check if you're changing other child of the parent node on which your `childEventListener` is set.

Comment: Please the code, to see it more clearly and please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i replied the post with code.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit guess is right. So it sounds like an answer :)

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: @AlberLevi did you try doing what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: yes i did it worked ty very much.

Answer (score 0):

So you should not be using a `childEventListener` because it fires whenever any child of the parent node changes.

You can check if you're updating other children of the parent node on which your `childEventListener` is set, along with others. That must be the case, for it to fire 3 times.

So you should rather focus on using a `singleValueEventListener` or a `valueEventListener` on the same reference you're using right now.

Read more about [childEventListeners here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener)

Understand more about [reading and writing on Firebase here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)